# Find out number of ios app installs/downloads

Tags: ios, app-store

How do I find out how many times a iOS app has been downloaded/installed by users. I am the developer of the app

Comment: iTunesconnect can get you this information, as can flurry.

Comment: I am on iTunesconnect and I cannot find any analytics - in particular, for the installs or uninstalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard way is to put some code in to 'phone home'.  Make sure you don't include any identifying information and use a secure connection.

The easy and best way is to look at your monthly report on itunesconnect.

Comment: i can't find the mentioned report.